# How can I use only a part of my assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to split the components of my applications like:

```
Application A -> Component X <- Application B
```

without compiling Component X to a dll.
When I include the .cs, Visual Studio copies it to the application directory. I don't want that. I want to include the file and then use a part of it, like C's #define. For example if I have a ZIP library, I don't want to include the whole assembly if I need a decompression. What's the C# way to make this? Can I somehow tell VS to not copy the file and use #defines or maybe some method attributes?

Comment: Very unclear.  Visual Studio does *not* copy .cs files and #define in C doesn't do what you want.  Are you talking about #include?  That's no different from just adding the same .cs file to multiple projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create a problem where there isn't any.

Create a new dll, and MOVE .cs files that should be shared there.  Build it, and have AppA and AppB reference and use that dll.

BTW, you can add reference from AppA to AppB, or from AppB to AppA, but not at the same time because it will create circular reference.

And if you want to stick to your idea, LINK your code files as Chris suggested, and use:

```
#if APPA
// code for AppA
#endif
```

To have pieces of code compile just in one application.  Use project level #defines (project properties) to define APPA and APPB in their respective projects.

[image: where to insert defines]

Answer (score 3):

An assembly is a single, complete file.  If you want multiple assemblies which are only included as needed, you need to build them using multiple projects (one per assembly) and reference only the ones you want in the downstream projects you want.

Bigger question, however, is ... Why?

Comment: Little remark: "An assembly is a single complete file" - it's not true, you can build multifile assemblies (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/226t7yxe.aspx)

Comment: Well  strictly speaking, an assembly *IS* a single, complete file. However, I agree that I am incorrect when I say "one per assembly".  Thanks, I actually wasn't aware of that.  But - that said - I dunno, if your project is complicated enough that you need to break it into multiple assemblies then IMO that's a clear indicator that the project itself needs some restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You can link to source files in Visual Studio, rather than copying them into in your project.  Right click on the folder where you want to put the file, click "Add Existing Item", find the file that you want to add in the dialog, and before hitting Open, note the little down arrow next to the Open button.  Click that, and click add as link.

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: There are a number of cases where that will cause problems - serialization for example. Just sayin'

Comment: What @blez does with it is his business :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add Existing Item...

Browse to the file you want to include.

Instead of selecting "add", press the arrow to the right of the "Add" button and select "Link" in the drop down.

/B

Answer (score 0):

May be you need [Multifile Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/168k2ah5.aspx)?